# Using AWS Lambda with Amazon DocumentDB Change Streams

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

I am looking to populate an SQS queue via a lambda function by listening to DocumentDB change streams. I know this can be done with [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb-example.html). Is there a way to achieve this with DocumentDB?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Amazon DocumentDB has a [change streams feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/change-streams.html) and you can use a Lambda function to get the change events and write them to another destination like SQS. There isn't currently a built-in integration between DocumentDB Change Streams and Lambda, so your Lambda will need to poll for change events and store the last processed event id externally (something like another DocumentDB collection or DynamoDB table). Please see [this video](https://www.twitch.tv/aws/video/510542149) that provides more details on how this can be done.